# Watch object state

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I was working with angular-js and came across interesting feature that can watch object for changes.

I wonder if there is something similar in c#. I thought to create some watcher that will accept object to be watched, and may be check the hash code of the object periodically to find out if object changed,  then rise an event. But that seems a bit inefficient.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The more common approach imho would be to implement the IntotifyPropertyChanged Interface to the classes which shall be observed and implement the event raising on the property setters for the properties you like.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That wouldn't work anyway, firstly because there is no requirement for a property change to affect the hash code, and secondly, even if it did affect the hash code, it would be possible for the new hash code to be equal to the old hash code.

What AngularJS does is keep track of the last-known values, and then re-load all of the values, comparing them to the prior ones. If they're no longer equal, there has been a change.

You could do the same in C# if you want to.

But a way that's more common in C# is for the object being watched to implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx), and raise the `PropertyChanged` event on each property change. This gives the object the ability to notify any interested watchers that properties have changed, without requiring the watcher to do any polling.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of the INotifyPropertyChanged, the only problem with this is that it can be used only when implementing my own class. So if i'm not the owner of the class and there is no override option for property i can't use it. that is the reason for the watcher and not subscriber)

Comment: @jekcom Then there is no other option but to re-read the properties periodically (or after some other less-specific event). As far as I know, there is no way built into the .NET Framework to do this, but it should be easy to create.

Comment: For a good hash code (which is used to compare objects) calculation, both your arguments should not hold (changed property should change hash and generally, hash should be different enough for any 2 different objects in 1^64 cases or more with low likelihood of collision). Main reason should be that the polling is not a good option. Also, like you say, PropertyChanged is the option though it does not come for free implementation-wise.

Comment: @AndreasReiff In the .NET world, hash codes are 32 bits, not 64 bits, making collisions far more likely even in an ideal distribution. But there are well-known hash collisions for extremely common values for extremely common types, such as `null`/`0` for type `int?`, so you don't even get that.

Answer (score 2):

In both JavaScript and C#, objects aren't *observable* *per se*.

Actually, Angular turns objects into observable objects under the hoods, and since JavaScript is a dynamically-typed language this conversion or wrapping can be done in a painless way.

Since C# is a strongly-typed language, you can't observe objects if they don't implement an interface or something that can expose an event to subscribe to changes. Usually observable objects should implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.

Other way of implementing this is using a framework like [Castle DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) to create proxies of your classes and intercept both method calls and property gets and sets.